# Java Split a String with coma or 0(zero) followed by a whitespace

Tags: java, regex, expression

If I have a string, e.g.

```
 s = "david,marko,rita,0 megan,0 vivian,law";
```

I need split this string into

```
david
marko
rita
megan
vivian
law
```

I am trying with

```
String arr[] = s.split("[,\\s]");
```

but didn´t work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this expression:

```
String arr[] = s.split(",0?\\s*");
```

Or maybe even:

```
String arr[] = s.split("[,0\\s]+");
```

Which one you want is unclear from the example.

Comment: the second option could not work with s = "da0vid,marko,rita,0 megan,0 vivian,law"; when I need 
da0vid
marko
rita
megan

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is : "(,0 |,)"

So try this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "david,marko,rita,0 megan,0 vivian,law";
        String[] ss = s.split("(,0 |,)");
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            String string = ss[i];
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice
Rather then splitting with multiple values try this

```
import java.util.*;
class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "david,marko,rita,0 megan,0 vivian,law";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.replace("0","").replace(" ","").split(",")));
  }
}
```

Comment: you can apply .replace only once for character "0 "

Comment: yeah it will work but those are some extra code , not optimized

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class SplitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "david,marko,rita,0 megan,0 vivian,law";
        String splits[] = inputString.split(",0?\\s*");
        for (String split : splits) {
            System.out.println(split);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arr = s.split(",(0\\s+)*");
```

The regex splits on a comma followed optionally by a 0 and one or more spaces.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         String s = "da0vid,marko,rita,0 megan,0 vivian,law";
         String[] arr = s.split(",(0\\s+)*");
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
           System.out.println("'"+arr[i]+"'");
      }

=>
'da0vid'
'marko'
'rita'
'megan'
'vivian'
'law'
```

Comment: Could you extend your answer to explain how this achieves the desired result?